# How to use a Pascal variable in Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascal

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; BeforeInstall: GetHome(); Flags: ignoreversion
[INI]
Filename: "{myVarFromPascal}\.MyProg\settings.ini"; Section: "Settings"; Key: "sound"; String: "1"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
[Code]
procedure GetHome();
     var
  myPascalVar: String;
begin
   RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Volatile Environment','USERPROFILE', myPascalVar);
   MsgBox('Value is "' + myPascalVar + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

These are my three example sections in INNO Setup. I want to use `myPascalVar` in the INI Section. How can I do it?

Comment: If you just want to read the registry, then note that you can use a `{reg:...}` constant instead.  Though be aware that reading from HKCU during install may not give you the results you are expecting if you're running as admin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to change your variable to be in the global scope and write a simple getter function for so called [`scripted constant`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm):

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; BeforeInstall: GetHome; Flags: ignoreversion

[INI]
Filename: "{code:GetMyVar}\.MyProg\settings.ini"; Section: "Settings"; Key: "sound"; String: "1"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist

[Code]
var
  myPascalVar: string;

function GetMyVar(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := myPascalVar;
end;

procedure GetHome;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Volatile Environment', 'USERPROFILE', myPascalVar);
  MsgBox('Value is "' + myPascalVar + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```