# InnoSetup: Generate Icons in Common/User Desktop based on values inside Installer

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

We provide a custom Wizard page in our InnoSetup configuration that gives us an `InstallForAllUsers` variable. Based on the value of this variable, we want to place our icons in the appropriate places `Common Desktop`/`Common Startup` for All Users, and `User Desktop`/`User Startup` for Current User.

Our Icons section looks like this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,MyApp}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: E:\Continuous Integration\InnoSetup Files\icon.ico
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{commonstartup}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename:  "{app}\MyApp.exe"
```

How can I leverage my `InstallForAllUsers` variable to replace these constants when necessary?

Comment: Look at [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19757381/960757) for instance. It should be applicable to your case as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I did since I used a similar thing for my Registry keys. Posting an answer right now. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Generally speaking, it is better to remove this choice from the UI than to try to implement it.  Changing where the icon goes does not make the difference between a per-user or per-machine install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Icons Section:

```
[Icons]    
Name: "{group}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,MyApp}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: E:\Continuous Integration\InnoSetup Files\icon.ico
Name: "{code:GetDesktopFolder}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{code:GetStartupFolder}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename:  "{app}\MyApp.exe"
```

### Code:

```
function GetDesktopFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  if (InstallAllUsers) then
    Result := ExpandConstant('{commondesktop}')
  else
    Result := ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}');
end;

function GetStartupFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  if (InstallAllUsers) then
    Result := ExpandConstant('{commonstartup}')
  else
    Result := ExpandConstant('{userstartup}');
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Check:` function that returns the "all users" variable to control whether the icon is created or not:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Check: Not CheckPerUserInstall;
Name: "{userdesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Check: CheckPerUserInstall;
Name: "{commonstartup}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename:  "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Check: Not CheckPerUserInstall;
Name: "{userstartup}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; IconFilename:  "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Check: CheckPerUserInstall;

[Code]
function CheckPerUserInstall(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := InstallForAllUsers;
end;
```

Note that the `{user*}` constants may very well be for a different user to the expected one if run from a limited user account. This is the primary reason why "per user" installs aren't that common anymore.